# How do I make an interval happen whenever I put a cursor on a button, and when your mouse gets out of the button, it clears the interval in JS / HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  <head> 
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function mouseOn() { 
      function int() { 
        document.getElementById("hover").click(); 
      } 
      var interval = setInterval(int, 0); 
    } 
    function mouseOff() { clearInterval(interval); } 
  </script>
</head> 
  <body> 
    <button id="hover" 
      onmouseenter="mouseOn();"
      onmouseleave="mouseOff();">
        Hover and Autoclick
    </button> 
  </body>
</html>
```

It doesn't autoclick when my mouse hovers on it. Do you guys know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only had one mistake in the initialization of the `interval` variable inside the function instead of in the main scope, I added a small check of the text changing to red when clicked and it works fine for me now

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var interval
            function mouseOn() {
                function int() {
                    document.getElementById("hover").click();
                }
             interval = setInterval(int, 0);
            }
            function mouseOff() {
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
    
            function test() {
                document.getElementById("hover").style.color = "red";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    
    <body> <button id="hover" onclick="test();" onmouseenter="mouseOn();" onmouseleave="mouseOff();">Hover and Autoclick</button> </body>
    
    </html>
```